# How to save a non ModelForm form to database in Django

Tags: python, django, forms

I'm a newbie Django user, struggling with submitting form data to the database. So that I can generate dynamic forms I am using a *non-ModelForm* form to capture field data.

I'm commented out validation for now but I am trying to capture the POST data from the form to the database. The latest 'draft' of my views.py code is as follows - most interested in format from `form_to_save = Scenario(...)`:

```
def scenario_add(request, mode_from_url):
    urlmap = {
        'aviation': 'Aviation',
        'maritime': 'Maritime',
        'international_rail': 'International Rail',
        'uk_transport_outside_london': 'UK Transport (Outside London)',
        'transport_in_london': 'Transport in London',
    }
    target_mode = urlmap[mode_from_url]
    m = Mode.objects.filter(mode=target_mode)
    tl = m[0].current_tl.threat_l
    scenario_form = ScenarioForm(request.POST or None, current_tl=tl, mode=target_mode)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        #if scenario_form.is_valid():
        form_to_save = Scenario(
            target = Target(descriptor = scenario_form.fields['target']),
            t_type = ThreatType(t_type = scenario_form.fields['t_type']),
            nra_reference = NraReference(nra_code = scenario_form.fields['nra_reference']),
            subt = scenario_form.fields['subt'],
            ship_t = ShipType(ship_t = scenario_form.fields['ship_t']),
            likelihood = scenario_form.fields['likelihood'],
            impact = scenario_form.fields['impact'],
            mitigation = scenario_form.fields['mitigation'],
            compliance_score = scenario_form.fields['compliance_score'],
            notes = scenario_form.fields['notes']
        )
        form_to_save.save()
        # This needs to be changed to a proper redirect or taken to
        # a scenario summary page (which doesn't yet exit.)
        return render(request, "ram/new_scenario_redirect.html", {
            'scenario_form': scenario_form,
            'mode': mode_from_url,
            'mode_proper': target_mode
        })
    else:
        # if there is no completed form then user is presented with a blank
        # form
        return render(request, 'ram/scenario_add.html', {
            'scenario_form': scenario_form,
            'current_tl': tl,
            'mode': mode_from_url,
            'mode_proper': target_mode
        })
```

Any advice gratefully received. Many thanks.

Comment: Why use a non model form to save in the database? ModelForms allow you to add extra fields (which are not bound to the db) and apply logic to them.

Comment: Because I want the HTML drop down `<options>` in the form to be dynamic based on arguments passed into the form class. Maybe there's an easier way to do this!

Comment: Very likely. You should ask a new question showing what you're currently doing and the expected behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

You've commented out the `is_valid` check, for some reason. You need that: as well as checking for validity, it also populates the form's `cleaned_data` dictionary which is what you should be getting the data from to create your object. (And don't call that object "form_to_save": it's a model instance, not a form).

```
if request.method == 'POST':
    if scenario_form.is_valid():
        scenario = Scenario(
            target = Target(descriptor=scenario_form.cleaned_data['target']),
            t_type = ThreatType(t_type = scenario_form.cleaned_data['t_type'])
            ...etc
```

Plus, you should move the final "return render" call out of the else block, so that it is caught when the form is *not* valid, to show any errors.

However, as petkostas says, you would almost certainly be better off using an actual ModelForm in the first place.

Comment: Hi thanks - see my comment to petkostas's question re not using a ModelForm. I'm adapting the form based on arguments passed from the calling view.

Answer (score 0):

You can add custom options by overriding the **init** function in your form.  For example:

```
class SomeForm(forms.Form):
    department = forms.ChoiceField(widget=forms.Select, required=True)
```

...

```
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(SomeForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['department'].choices = Department.objects.all().order_by('department_name).values_list('pk', 'department_name')
```

You can also change the queryset in the init function:
where Department is a foreign key for example

```
queryset = Department.objects.filter(your logic)
self.fields['department'].queryset = queryset
```